# Poorly formatted CSV file (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, csv, formatting

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
account,name,,,,type,"$a,mount.00",description
account,name,so,me,thing,type,$amount,"description
account,name,so,me,thing
account,name,so,me,thing,type,$amount,"description"
```

Basically, I want to sanitize the entire file and I think the easiest way to do it would be to just add quotes to every column and make sure that every row had 13 columns.  The only issue is, some columns have opening quotes, but no closing quotes.  This only appears to happen at the end of the row, but the file is so large, that I can't completely verify that.

What would be the best way to sanitize this via Perl?

Thanks!
- Matt

Comment: You mean add double quotes?

Comment: The problem is with the columns with opening, no closing quotes. There is really no way to know where the closing quote goes. Example `account,name,,,,type,"$a,mount.00`, the closing quote could be `account,name,,,,type,"$a",mount.00` or `account,name,,,,type,"$a,mount.00"`

Comment: If there is really *"no way to know where the closing quote goes"* then I don't see how we can help you. Only you know your data sufficiently well to describe how it should be sanitised. Once you have done that you are welcome to help with implementing it in Perl.

Comment: @Borodin - I wasn't the one that said that there's "no way to know".

Comment: Does any of the field *data* contain commas or double-quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) to load the file and let it handle the sanitizing. It's pretty good at that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ 
  binary => 1, 
  allow_loose_quotes => 1, 
  always_quote => 1 
});

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    push @rows, $row;
}

$csv->eol ("\n");
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, $_) for @rows;

__DATA__
account,name,,,,type,"$a,mount.00",description
account,name,so,me,thing,type,$amount,"description
account,name,so,me,thing
account,name,so,me,thing,type,$amount,"description"
```

It will produce the following output:

```
"account","name","","","","type","$a,mount.00","description"
"account","name","so","me","thing","type","$amount","""description"
"account","name","so","me","thing"
"account","name","so","me","thing","type","$amount","description"
```

Note how all fields are quoted. It considered the single (unclosed) double-quote in line two as a literal quote instead of an unclosed quoting of the field and escaped it. By default, it uses a double-quote as the escape character. I left it like that, but you can change it by setting `$csv->escape_char('\\')` or similar.